# Uncertainty principle relation for virtual particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, virtual-particles

I have heard from a physicist uncertainty principle as we know it $$\Delta E \cdot \Delta t \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$$ holds only for **REAL** particles.

For **VIRTUAL** particles (in vacuum fluctuation), the relation bellow must hold:
$$\Delta E \cdot \Delta t < \frac{\hbar}{2}$$

I could not find this anywhere. Is that correct?